# Error while trying to phrase JSON with Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, jsondecoder

I'm trying to receive data from a JSON link in Swift Playground on Mac, I've struct all the data, but I'm having issue trying to decode all of the data, receiving the error: "Referencing instance method 'decode(_:from:)' on 'Array' requires that 'Bicimia' conform to 'Decodable'"

I've already tries to add the Codable/Decodable option, and tried to change the URLSession respectively, but nothing has changed.

```
struct Bicimia {

    let network: Network

}


struct Network {

    let company: [String]
    let href, id: String
    let location: Location
    let name: String
    let stations: [Station]

}

struct Location {

    let city, country: String
    let latitude, longitude: Double

}

struct Station {

    let emptySlots: Int
    let extra: Extra
    let freeBikes: Int
    let id: String
    let latitude, longitude: Double
    let name, timestamp: String

}

struct Extra {

    let extraDescription: String
    let status: Status

}

enum Status {

    case online
}


let url = "https://api.citybik.es/v2/networks/bicimia"
let urlOBJ = URL(string: url)

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlOBJ!) {(data, response, error) in


    do {
        let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([Bicimia].self, from: data!)
        print(res)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}.resume()
```

Comment: Do what the error suggests: Add conformance to `Decodable` to all structs. `struct ... : Decodable {`

Comment: I've already tried adding :Decodable to all struct, but I receive an error that says: "Type 'Extra' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'"

Comment: Add conformance to `Decodable` also to the enum `Status`

Comment: Type 'Status' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

Comment: Looking at the JSON `Status` has cases `online` and `offline` so change the enum to `enum Status : String, Decodable { case online, offline }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be `Decodable` all properties should be `Decodable` down the chain:

```
struct Bicimia: Decodable {
    let network: Network // should be decodable
}

struct Network: Decodable {
    let company: [String]
    let href, id: String
    let location: Location // should be decodable
    let name: String
    let stations: [Station] // should be decodable
}

struct Location: Decodable {
    let city, country: String
    let latitude, longitude: Double
}

struct Station: Decodable {
    let emptySlots: Int
    let extra: Extra // should be decodable
    let freeBikes: Int
    let id: String
    let latitude, longitude: Double
    let name, timestamp: String
}

struct Extra: Decodable {
    let extraDescription: String
    let status: Status // should be decodable
}

enum Status: String, Decodable {
    case online
}
```

Note that `enum`s can not be `Decodable` alone, because they should know what is the raw value, or you should manually decode them in `decode` function.

Comment: That worked without problem, but now in the terminal I receive an error saying: "typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))"

Comment: use `let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Bicimia.self, from: data!)` instead of [Bicimia.self]...

Comment: That is another issue, but you should decode as @StephanSchlecht mentioned. Please do not ask another question in the comment. Except, feel free [to ask a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you need to. And don't forget to **mark as answer** if this was the answer to the original question as you said.